# VS Code ssh remote is not opening file in new tabs

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

Recently vs code got updated and post that all files of remote server is opening in one tab only. Tab feature is working fine when opening files from local machine but when connected to remote server on ssh, only one file is opening. Tried many suggestions shown in online forums but nothing is working. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was intermittent issue, i could not fix it but i found workaround for this while connected to remote servers. There is option to keep the tab open. Hope it helps anyone who is having similar issues.